# How to auto-close the Sound Bar Indicator

Tags: stock-android, 7.0-nougat, nexus-6p, nexus

I have an issue (or at least I perceive it to be since it wasn't like that in the first place) on my **Nexus 6p** where after I click the volume buttons while my device is on, the sound bar indicator does not auto close like it used to. I am forced to click somewhere on the screen for the sound bar to close, rather than waiting a couple seconds for it to automatically do so. This is a small but rather annoying problem for me and occurred after factory resetting my device. I am running stock **Android 7.1.1 Nougat** and am not rooted.

[image]

Comment: It requires you to click outside to indicate you are through with it. People tend to finagle the sound slider to taste - a little up - a little down - a little bitta dis - a little bitta dat. It will not know your intentional changes are complete until you indicate you are through by clicking outside. It is being courteous, believing taste is continually refined, rather than singly perfected.

Comment: I understand but it wasn't like that before. I would like the device to be at it's previous state where the sound bar auto-closes in around 5 seconds or so when you don't touch your phone.